# Next without For, End If without If

Tags: vba, for-loop, if-statement, compiler-errors, runtime

I am struggling with my code below. In this version, I get a "next without for error"

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim Lookup As Worksheet, Data As Worksheet, PF As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, LR As Long, LookupCounter As Long, i As Long, j As Long
  
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set Lookup = .Worksheets("Lookup")
        Set Data = .Worksheets("Data")
        Set PF = .Worksheets("PF")
    End With
    
    LastRow = Data.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LR = PF.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LookupCounter = 2
    
    For i = 2 To LastRow
    For j = 2 To LR
        

    If Intersect(Lookup.Range("A2"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ' clear sheet
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Lookup.Range("A2").Value = UCase(Lookup.Range("A2"))
        Lookup.Range("B2:H2000").Clear
        ' get data
        
           If Lookup.Range("A2") = Data.Cells(i, 2) Then
               Lookup.Cells(LookupCounter, 3).Value = Data.Cells(i, 1)
               Lookup.Cells(LookupCounter, 4).Value = Data.Cells(i, 9)
               LookupCounter = LookupCounter + 1
        
            ElseIf Lookup.Range("A2") = PF.Cells(j, 2) Then
                Lookup.Cells(LookupCounter, 6).Value = PF.Cells(j, 1)
                Lookup.Cells(LookupCounter, 7).Value = PF.Cells(j, 12)
                Lookup.Cells(LookupCounter, 8).Value = PF.Cells(j, 10)
                Lookup.Cells(LookupCounter, 9).Value = PF.Cells(j, 2)
                LookupCounter = LookupCounter + 1
        
        Lookup.Range("C2:C2000").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
        Lookup.Range("F2:F2000").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
        Lookup.Range("H2:H2000").Style = "Currency"
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
    End If
    
    Next
    
End Sub
```

In this version, I also get the error "next without for"

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim Lookup As Worksheet, Data As Worksheet, PF As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, LR As Long, LookupCounter As Long, i As Long, j As Long
  
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set Lookup = .Worksheets("Lookup")
        Set Data = .Worksheets("Data")
        Set PF = .Worksheets("PF")
    End With
    
    LastRow = Data.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LR = PF.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LookupCounter = 2
    
    For i = 2 To LastRow
    For j = 2 To LR
        

    If Intersect(Lookup.Range("A2"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ' clear sheet
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Lookup.Range("A2").Value = UCase(Lookup.Range("A2"))
        Lookup.Range("B2:H2000").Clear
        ' get data
        
           If Lookup.Range("A2") = Data.Cells(i, 2) Then
               Lookup.Cells(LookupCounter, 3).Value = Data.Cells(i, 1)
               Lookup.Cells(LookupCounter, 4).Value = Data.Cells(i, 9)
               LookupCounter = LookupCounter + 1
        
            ElseIf Lookup.Range("A2") = PF.Cells(j, 2) Then
                Lookup.Cells(LookupCounter, 6).Value = PF.Cells(j, 1)
                Lookup.Cells(LookupCounter, 7).Value = PF.Cells(j, 12)
                Lookup.Cells(LookupCounter, 8).Value = PF.Cells(j, 10)
                Lookup.Cells(LookupCounter, 9).Value = PF.Cells(j, 2)
                LookupCounter = LookupCounter + 1
        
        Lookup.Range("C2:C2000").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
        Lookup.Range("F2:F2000").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
        Lookup.Range("H2:H2000").Style = "Currency"
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
    End If
    
    Next
    
End Sub
```

And if I remove both "Next" statements, I get a "End if without block if" as an error... I can't even tell if my code works, I am getting frustrated moving around my "next" and "end if" statements, I can't get it right. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Missing a  `Next` in the first snippet. You have two `For` loops.

Comment: Also missing an `end if` in the first snippet.

Comment: Proper indentation would help you spot these issues.

Comment: I tried but I am still getting an "end if without block if" error, I see now where my `Next` (I hope), but I'm still not getting the `End If` right.

Comment: right before this line `Lookup.Range("C2:C2000").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"`

Comment: You need to develop some good coding styles for blocks so that you type the block closure immediately after typing the block opener. e.g.after typing a for line you immediately enter three blank lines followed by a next and then go back two lines to enter your code.  Similar for if then end if etc.  Also, if you are learning, for 'For' loops it can be useful to add the control varlable to the next statement so that you have matching pairs.

Comment: You're right, I'm a novice to coding but I'm working on better habits.

Comment: Use the RubberDuck to automatically indent your code. It will also teach you many concepts through the Code Inspections feature. https://rubberduckvba.com/

Comment: Thank you, great website! I am no longer getting the if and next errors, and now I know that the code is still not working the way I want it to haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code there are a number of redundant activities in the for loops.  With a bit of restructuring you can get a clearer picture is what is happening.  I've no idea if the code below reproduces your intent but it is an example of how to write better VBA (IMHO).  Incidentally, the code compiles and does not trigger any Rubberduck inspections.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal ipTarget As Range)
    ' if you use consistent naming you always know where to look
    ' for the definition of a variable
    ' I use the following prefixes
    ' * ip for an input parameter
    ' * op for an output only parameter
    ' * iop for a parameter that can have its value changed for use outside the method
    ' * my for variables declared inside a method
    
    ' Avoid using 'With' if you can use a simpler qualifying scheme
    
    Dim myWb As Workbook
    Set myWb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' The guard clause should come as early as possible
    If Intersect(myWb.Worksheets.Item("Lookup").Range("A2"), ipTarget) Is Nothing Then
        
        Exit Sub
            
    End If
  
   ' Don't put things inside loops if they only need to be done once
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
    Dim myLookup As worksheet
    Set myLookup = myWb.Worksheets.Item("Lookup")
    
    ' clear sheet
    ' also a clear use case for the With construct
    With myLookup
    
        .Range("A2").Value = UCase$(myLookup.Range("A2").Value)
        .Range("B2:H2000").Clear
        .Range("C2:C2000").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
        .Range("F2:F2000").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
        .Range("H2:H2000").Style = "Currency"
    
    End With
        
    Dim myData As worksheet
    Set myData = myWb.Worksheets.Item("Data")
    Dim myLastRow As Long
    ' Unqualified reference to Rows replaced with myData.Rows
    myLastRow = myData.Cells.Item(myData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' seems like you have another 'lastrow' here?
    Dim myPF As worksheet
    Set myPF = myWb.Worksheets.Item("PF")
    Dim myLR As Long
    'Unqualified reference to Rows replaced with myPfRows.
    myLR = myPF.Cells.Item(myPF.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim myLookupCounter As Long
    myLookupCounter = 2
    
    ' Although you will see it used frequently, i,j,k
    ' as variables for loop counters is poor coding
    ' much better to use meaningful names.
    
    Dim myRow As Long
    For myRow = 2 To myLastRow
    
         ' Sorry no idea what a good name would be here as there isn't
         ' enough information
        Dim myAltRow As Long
        For myAltRow = 2 To myLR
        
            With myLookup
            
               If .Range("A2").Value = myData.Cells.Item(myRow, 2) Then
               
                   .Cells.Item(myLookupCounter, 3).Value = myData.Cells.Item(myRow, 1)
                   .Cells.Item(myLookupCounter, 4).Value = myData.Cells.Item(myRow, 9)
                   myLookupCounter = myLookupCounter + 1
            
                ElseIf .Range("A2").Value = myPF.Cells.Item(myAltRow, 2) Then
                
                    .Cells.Item(myLookupCounter, 6).Value = myPF.Cells.Item(myAltRow, 1)
                    .Cells.Item(myLookupCounter, 7).Value = myPF.Cells.Item(myAltRow, 12)
                    .Cells.Item(myLookupCounter, 8).Value = myPF.Cells.Item(myAltRow, 10)
                    .Cells.Item(myLookupCounter, 9).Value = myPF.Cells.Item(myAltRow, 2)
                    myLookupCounter = myLookupCounter + 1
                    
                ' what happens if neither of the two conditions above is met?
                'else
                
                    '??????
                
                End If
                
            End With
   
        Next myAltRow
    
    Next myRow
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to fix the code! I definitely found your tips helpful, but unfortunately, the code is still not doing what I want it to do. Basically, if the name "John Smith" is typed into sheet 1, then all the data related to "John Smith" in the other two sheets will be available in sheet 1. Right now though, I'm getting a return when I type in a name, but it doesn't actually match the data sets.

Comment: I'm afraid your comment doesn't make much sense in the context of the code posted.  Its also difficult to make further recommendations without seeing the content of the spreadsheets.

Comment: That's fair, I'll have a crack at it and if it doesn't work for me I'll post another question.